# Find the distance between two Zip Code using Webservices?

Tags: web-services, distance, zipcode

Are there any good Webservices apart from Google one which can find me the distance between two Zip Codes?

I have

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=95050&destinations=94087&mode=bicycling&sensor=false`

which is Google API. Are there any other API's that I can take a look? If yes, can anyone provide me the link for the same?

Comment: you could rerfer to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426710/how-to-find-the-distance-between-two-zipcodes-using-java-code

Comment: in that post, mostly it talk about using Java code.

Comment: You can use https://thezipcodes.com/ to get location from ZIP Code and calculate distance.
To integrate with your service follow http://thezipcodes.com/docs

Answer (score 4):

There is a very simple API that will calculate distance between two zip codes.  There are also options for zipcodes within a radius and finding the lat/long and city/state.  http://zipcodedistanceapi.redline13.com/

Comment: It's not giving the correct result as it differs from that of google map.
I tested it for the following zip codes:
_Origin = 76180
Destination = 75029_
This API gives **19.829** miles while google map shows **25.8** miles.

Comment: This API gives end to end distance between the two zip codes, not a travelling distance. That's why, the google map shows different distance.

Comment: The best API so far is google map API  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/